# When trying to get data from the database instead of the object, I get undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, mongodb

When I use this function

(updating)

## Property.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getProperty } from '../../utils/api'

const Property = () => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation()
    const id = pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0]
    const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery(["resd", id], async () => await getProperty(id))
    console.log(data)
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            This is individual property path
        </div>
    )
};

export default Property
```

I should get the data from the database as object but I get "undefined"

This is my

## api.js function

```
export const getProperty = async(id) => {
    try {
        const response = await api.get(`/residency/${id}`, {
            timeout: 10 * 1000,
        });

        if(response.status === 400 || response.status === 500)
        {
            throw response.data
        }
        return response.data
    } catch (error) {
        toast.error("Something went wrong")
        throw error
    }
}
```

This is my data and in response I want to get a specific item by its id

## my data example

```
[
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "64392d39dfd90fb29e464fb7" },
    "title": "Sunny Meadow Cottage",
    "description": "Massive opportunity to build your dream home at the base of Mummy Mountain in the 3 C's school district. Home is currently updated and very livable if your plans are to build at a later date.* Bonus * to live hillside without hillside restrictions in the town of PV. Run don't walk to capture this needle in a hay stack.",
    "price": 6000,
    "address": "Street 1",
    "city": "Chicago",
    "country": "US",
    "image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/7031406/pexels-photo-7031406.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
    "userEmail": "mukhtarhamza294@gmail.com",
    "createdAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T10:38:48.762Z" },
    "updatedAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T10:38:48.762Z" },
    "facilities": { "bathrooms": "2", "parking": "1", "bedrooms": "5" }
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "64392e0bdfd90fb29e464fbc" },
    "title": "Coastal Breeze Villa",
    "description": "Massive opportunity to build your dream home at the base of Mummy Mountain in the 3 C's school district. Home is currently updated and very livable if your plans are to build at a later date.* Bonus * to live hillside without hillside restrictions in the town of PV. Run don't walk to capture this needle in a hay stack.",
    "price": 8000,
    "address": "Street 2",
    "city": "Multan",
    "country": "Pakistan",
    "image": "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-84l-BoUL090/VTDHcQzSTNI/AAAAAAAAuHI/Khftta_CF5E/s1920/wow-home-design.jpg",
    "facilities": { "bathrooms": "5", "parking": "1", "bedrooms": "4" },
    "userEmail": "mukhtarhamza294@gmail.com",
    "createdAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T10:42:19.231Z" },
    "updatedAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T10:42:19.231Z" }
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "6439001c74446601d6fce96d" },
    "title": "Citralan Puri Serang",
    "description": "Massive opportunity to build your dream home at the base of Mummy Mountain in the 3 C's school district. Home is currently updated and very livable if your plans are to build at a later date.* Bonus * to live hillside without hillside restrictions in the town of PV. Run don't walk to capture this needle in a hay stack.",
    "price": 3000,
    "address": "Street 3",
    "city": "California",
    "country": "US",
    "image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/323780/pexels-photo-323780.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
    "userEmail": "mukhtarhamza294@gmail.com",
    "createdAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T07:26:20.051Z" },
    "updatedAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T07:26:20.051Z" },
    "facilities": { "bathrooms": "3", "parking": "1", "bedrooms": "2" }
  }]
```

I've tried adding console.log to my API and Property.jsx to check if the response is coming from the database, but I only get "undefined". Last time, with a similar problem, the problem was the wrong type of the hook, but I did not fully understand how to edit it.

Comment: so `return response.data` is returning `undefined`? what is the content of `response`?

Comment: Is the API endpoint ```/residency/${id}``` is correct and returning the expected data?

Comment: @JaromandaX Already update my question

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation yes, this endpoint is correct

Comment: If that is `response` (since you said response.data is undefined), it is an array, and has no `data` property

Comment: @JaromandaX But it does not return this array for some reason

Comment: It seems you're passing the function itself as the second argument to ```useQuery```, instead of calling it. So this maybe the reason why you get ```undefined```. You should do it like this, ```const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery(["resd", id], () => getProperty(id))```.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation Oh, thank you, it's true, I need to be a little more careful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need wait for the request complete,then the data will auto update

```js
const Property = () => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation()
    const id = pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0]
    const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery(["resd", id], async () => await getProperty(id))
    if(data){
      console.log(data)
    }
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            This is individual property path
        </div>
    )
};
```